# What is the best way to iterate over multiple lists in the same method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I need to achieve a result that give me 4 different sums after iterate over lists in a single method in Java.

I have 4 different lists with a lot of entries, and i need to iterate in the same way over those 4 lists. Whats the best way to do it, and maintain the best possible performance. Should i implement some Thread Pool? or does not really matter? The lists have around 500 entries each.

Thank you.

Comment: "_Should i implement some Thread Pool? or does not really matter?_" You should just do it anyway that you can and IF you see performance problems then you can worry about micro optimizations.

Comment: Java 8 lambdas are born for this.  You can pass different methods to map/reduce over a stream.  Bonus points for using parallel stream to perform it in parallel automatically.  Use the java.util.function machinery to do it.

Comment: 500 element lists are tiny. Profile it yourself, but I can't imagine iterating the list 4 times in a single thread taking very long (unless you are using a very poor List implementation).

Comment: Could you show us your current implementation? What is wrong with it? I don't think you want to bother yourself with any Thread Pool. If it is critical for you, you can simply execute processing of each list in a separate thread. But for 4 lists with 500 entries I don't think it is really what you want.

Comment: @duffymo - I recently read an article that said, in essence, that parallel stream overhead wasn't worth it unless you were working on large datasets, and 500 isn't "large". Wish I could find the article again to cite.

Comment: Iterate in the same way? As in do the exact same thing on all four? Just create a method which takes those lists as parameters and does it's work

Comment: @StephenP Effective Java, er, effectively says that.

Comment: Agreed, @StephenP.  I would not recommend using parallel until a need was demonstrated.  Lambdas are still the way to go here, whether you parallelize or not.  They allow it to be added easily if needed.

Comment: @Frontear Yes thats exactly what i though, i just wanted to see some extra opinions on the topic.

Comment: @duffymo That was my doubt if it would be worth or not, ill check Lambdas out, Thank you for your feedback guys!

Comment: I believe parallelStream will partition the stream according to the # of cores available.  It will not be prey to context switching issues that will happen if you use more threads than cores.  With that said it's always advisable to measure before deciding.  Do it with stream and parallelStream and measure the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way I can think of:

```java
IntStream
  .range(0,4)
  .parallel()
  .foreach(i -> 
    lists[i]
    .stream()
    .parallel()
    .forEach(item -> operation(item)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will definitely check try it out! :)